# How to include Groovy or Java annotations in Gradle's generated groovydocs?

Tags: gradle, groovy, groovydoc

For example, I have the following code in `UserController.groovy`:

```
/**
 * Retrieves all users from the database.
 *
 * @return A list of all users from the database.
 */
@GetMapping
@ApiOperation(value = 'Retrieves all users from the database.')
ResponseEntity<List<UserEntity>> get() {
    ResponseEntity.ok().body(userService.getAllUsers())
}
```

...which, when generated by Gradle's `groovydoc` task, produces this:

[image: Groovydoc generated documentation]

However, I would like the `groovydoc` task to be able to parse method annotations and display them like [Spring's API docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html):

[image: Sring API Docs]

Is there a way to configure the `groovydoc` Gradle task to do that, or do I need to use another library or tool?

Comment: Are the annotations in question marked with `@Documented`?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown - No, those are Swagger annotations.

Comment: I thought annotations that are not marked with `@Documented` were not supposed to be represented in generated javadocs.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown - If I do put `@Documented` on the class, I get a compiler error that says `'@Documented' not applicable to type`